# How to apply multiple conditions in Datatable.Select in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to apply multiple conditions in Datatable.Select query how can I do this.

Below is the code that I have:

```
dvOrg.Table.Select("customer_type_id='64501'", "sort_column");
```

Now I want to apply one more condition `covered_patient_type='Inpatient'`.
I tried this but it did not work.

```
dvOrg.Table.Select("customer_type_id='64501' and covered_patient_type='Inpatient'", "sort_column");
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `But it did not work`  what did not work? did you get an error message? did you get any results? Is customer_type_id a string?

Comment: customer_type_id is not a string it is a number.

Comment: then don't put single quotes around it.

Comment: That doesn't matter in this case, the focus is on why `covered_patient_type` is not matching any rows

Comment: To make this a better question you should include the schema and example data rows in your post. The issue is likely going to be the value that you are using for `'Inpatient'` it might not match the values in the underlying data table.

Comment: If you are having difficulty writing queries of this kind, consider using [LINQ to DataSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/queries-in-linq-to-dataset).

Answer (score 1):

If your code still doesn't work, try building up the filter by adding conditions one by one.

```
dvOrg.RowFilter = "customer_type_id='64501'";
dvOrg.RowFilter += " and covered_patient_type='Inpatient'";
dvOrg.Sort = "sort_column";
```

And just double-check whether your data types are in the correct form.

Answer (score 0):

The code for this is correct, which means the problem will be related to the specific data schema and the data types.

This fiddle proves the concept, selecting by multiple columns is similar to SQL WHERE clause, using `AND` to append additional column criteria. In this OP is correct.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/7cPr5H

```
dvOrg.Table.Select("customer_type_id='64501' and covered_patient_type='Inpatient'", "id DESC");
```

This works only if the `covered_patient_type` is implicitly castable to a string.

For this data, we can see that `customer_type_id` is an int, but in the filter we can expect it to be a string and the filter condition still works:

```
[{"id":1623,"customer_type_id":645,"covered_patient_type":"Outpatient","expectation":"filtered out"},
{"id":1624,"customer_type_id":645,"covered_patient_type":"Inpatient","expectation":"filtered out"},
{"id":1625,"customer_type_id":64501,"covered_patient_type":"Outpatient","expectation":"filtered out"},
{"id":1626,"customer_type_id":64501,"covered_patient_type":"Inpatient","expectation":"selected"},
{"id":1627,"customer_type_id":64501,"covered_patient_type":"Outpatient","expectation":"filtered out"},
{"id":1628,"customer_type_id":64501,"covered_patient_type":"Inpatient","expectation":"selected"},
{"id":1629,"customer_type_id":64501,"covered_patient_type":"Outpatient","expectation":"filtered out"}]
```

```
Filter By two columns: customer_type_id='64501' and covered_patient_type='Inpatient'
ID:1628, expectation:selected, customer_type_id:64501, covered_patient_type:Inpatient
ID:1626, expectation:selected, customer_type_id:64501, covered_patient_type:Inpatient
```

The common scenario where this isn't straight forward are when `covered_patient_type` is stored as an integer (or some other type where the value is a reference to another list, or enum and you are resolving the visible value in the view.

In that case you need to filter on the underlying value, if `"Inpatient"` in the view is an enum, cast it to an int, or if `"Inpatient"` is a vlaue from a related table or otherwise unreleated list, resolve the pointer value that matches the value used int underlying DataTable dataset.

> All of this is easily resolved by including the raw DataTable in your original post. But I hope this thought process will help you explore these concepts on your own.